# Eclipse on Linux does not display options for C++ New Project

Tags: c++, eclipse

I recently installed Linux, from there I installed Eclipse, from there I installed the Eclipse PDE module, from there I installed CDT debug and CDT build tools.  However when I go to create new project -> C++ -> I get an empty window...and I can not click next.

Seems like Eclipse is still missing something that I need to install.

Comment: Did you ever find out what was causing this?

Comment: No....I just debug PHP manually.

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion would be to uninstall the eclipse you have, and install cdt directly, available [here](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/).